# ssrs decimal rounding

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In the `SSRS Reports`
the output for `round(417.504,2)` is 
giving `417.51`

Is there any function or option to get the my desired Rounding value

I want it to be:

```
 round(417.504,2)=417.50
```

Comment: What about rounding at the data source?

Answer (score 0):

It will be good approach to get the formatted data from the database and for that do the rounding on database as suggested by @BIDude

But if the database query is not under your control then you can use the following

```
 = Math.Round(417.5042,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```